# How can I tell how a panel item was set up

Tags: xubuntu, panel

I need to do some major surgery on a user account that has somehow sustained configuration damage to the point window decorations are gone, some apps don't listen to the keyboard, etc etc.

I run xfce4 sessions.  There's a panel on the top of the screen that has applications that I put there once upon a time.  I know how to do that, sort of.  But I don't remember the details of what I specified.  And I'm unaware of an app for the panel that's like the menu editor that lets you see and manipulate an item that's already there.

I want to do that because I want to re-do this stuff in a different account.  Or possibly do a dotfile transplant on this account and re-edit to include the stuff I'm used to.

Answer (score 2):

Right-click the panel, choose Panel preferences. In tab Elements, you'll see the list of items in the panel.

On my system, the panels are described in `~/.config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/xfce4-panel.xml`, however I found launcher-related information under `~/.config/xfce4/panel/launcher-*`.